# How to make a two columns into row and remaining as it is in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

My table consists of following data

```
ID | ST_NAME|   ST_DATE_TIME|   ST_SPEED
-----------------------------------------------    
1  |E11|July, 14 2013 01:00:00+0000|    106
3  |E10 |July, 14 2013 02:00:00+0000|   124
4  |E10 |July, 14 2013 03:00:00+0000|   117
5  |E10 |July, 15 2013 01:00:00+0000|   124
6  |E10 |July, 15 2013 02:00:00+0000|   106
7  |E10 |July, 15 2013 03:00:00+0000|   106
```

I need the following result

```
ST_Name| 1:00| 2:00| 3:00| ... |24:00
E11|106|  Null| Null|.... |Null
E10|124|.....
```

Make each hour and st_name as a column. Sum of speed of each st_name as row

This what i tried

```
SELECT 
   '01:00' as "01:00", '02:00' as "02:00", '03:00' as "03:00" .... '24:00' as     "24:00"
FROM
   (SELECT
       ST_SPEED, substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ST_DATE_TIME, 114), 1, 5) AS p 
FROM t_data) AS s
PIVOT
   (SUM(ST_SPEED) FOR p in ("01:00", "02:00", "03:00")) AS PivotTable
```

but showing some other result pls help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ST_NAME CHAR(3),
    ST_DATE_TIME DATETIME,
    ST_SPEED TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO @t (ST_NAME, ST_DATE_TIME, ST_SPEED)
VALUES 
    ('E11', '20130714 01:00:00', 106),
    ('E10', '20130714 02:00:00', 124),
    ('E10', '20130714 03:00:00', 117),
    ('E10', '20130715 01:00:00', 124),
    ('E10', '20130715 02:00:00', 106),
    ('E10', '20130715 03:00:00', 106)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ST_NAME, ST_SPEED, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), ST_DATE_TIME, 8) AS p 
    FROM @t
) s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(ST_SPEED) FOR p IN (
        [01:00], [02:00], [03:00], 
        [04:00], [05:00], [06:00], 
        [07:00], [08:00], [09:00],
        [10:00], [11:00], [12:00],
        [13:00], [14:00], [15:00],
        [16:00], [17:00], [18:00],
        [19:00], [20:00], [21:00],
        [22:00], [23:00], [24:00])
) p
```

Output -

```
ST_NAME 01:00       02:00       03:00       04:00       05:00       06:00       07:00       08:00       09:00       10:00       11:00       12:00       13:00       14:00       15:00       16:00       17:00       18:00       19:00       20:00       21:00       22:00       23:00       24:00
------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
E10     124         230         223         NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
E11     106         NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```